# Rollup plugin postcss does not inject css imported from node_modules

Tags: reactjs, node-modules, rollupjs, rollup-plugin-postcss

Here is my rollup config

```
// rollup.config.js
const postcss = require('rollup-plugin-postcss');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');

module.exports = {
  rollup(config, _options) {
    config.plugins.push(
      postcss({
        plugins: [
          autoprefixer(),
        ],
        extensions: ['.css'],
        modules: false,
        extract: false,
      }),
    );
    return config;
  },
};
```

So if I import css file local from a relative path, it gets injected but I import from node_modules it doesn't

```
import React from 'react';
import { toast } from 'react-toastify';
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';
// The following works if I copy the file locally
// import './ReactToastify.css';
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

I came across exactly the same problem and I think I found the solution. The trick here is to use `rollup-plugin-postcss` (or also `rollup-plugin-styles`) in combination with `@rollup/plugin-node-resolve`.

My `rollup.config.js` looks something like this:

```
import { nodeResolve } from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve'
import postcss from 'rollup-plugin-postcss'
// import styles from 'rollup-plugin-styles'

export default {
  ...
  plugins: [
    postcss(),
    // styles(),
    nodeResolve({
      extensions: ['.css']
    })
  ]
};
```

As far as I can tell, for my simple case, it doesn't matter if you use postcss or styles plugins. Both work the same.

Comment: Sorry for late posting. I had a different issue and it was because of a sideEffect property present in package.json of the requested node module. May be that has been done for webpack 5 treeshaking but we don't have any control over that. So I just copied that css into my source code.

Comment: I also have the problem that imports from node_modules do not get injected. What sideEffect property was that which caused the problem? For me it happens with all CSS from all node modules

Comment: you are a star @samuelg0rd0n - thank you!

Comment: I'm getting errors on both postcss and styles :/. Each showing different css syntax errors